# Upload large data to Google drive gives 400 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am trying to insert file using Google Drive API. Package PYthon API Client V3.
**It works fine when the file size is small**, but, starts giving these errors when the file size goes to 15MB or more.

This error is shown up consistently.

```
An error occured: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&convert=true&alt=json returned "Invalid Upload Request">
```

### Code:

Am using *MediaInMemoryUpload* with *resumable=True* as suggested for large files.

```
file = service.files().insert(body={'title': title, 'description': description, 
      'mimeType':mime_type,'writersCanShare':False}, convert=True,
       media_body=MediaInMemoryUpload(fileData,body["mimeType"], resumable=True)).execute()
```

*fileData* has 32MB string of data to be saved as spreadsheet in drive. 
I tried with both *convert=True and False*, Guessing its not able to convert large files to spreadsheet, Hoping it to save as a file in drive, not as spreadsheet. Any case the issues is same.

Any one any idea of finding solutions for this??

Comment: Did you try catching the exception and retrying, as suggested at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload ?

Comment: ya did try many times with different file sizes. it has exponential back offs implemented with code, so big files any number of time same issue.

Answer (score 0):

While not a full answer as I don't know how to fix this in python, I believe Google Drive requires multipart uploads (multiple requests with the file split into sections) for uploads larger than 5MB. See https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#multipart